# MAMP PRO on OSX 10.7 Lion Does not shutdown properly

Tags: macos, osx-lion, mamp

It seems that MAMP Pro is not allowing the OS to properly shut down.  With MAMP Pro running, selecting Shutdown from the Apple menu results in the system sitting there, not doing anything.  Then, bringing the MAMP Pro window to the front and trying to Quit does nothing.

Opening Activity Monitor and Quitting the process shuts MAMP Pro down - then I can shut down the system.

If I open the main window of MAMP Pro and manually stop the services then quit it stops normally and lets the computer shutdown as expected.

Any ideas as to how to get around this?

**UPDATE**:
I've also looked into trying this:
http://www.46palermo.com/blog/run-mamp-without-password-easy-way/ as another way to start MAMP PRO but I can't get that to work at all for some reason.

There is a [forum entry on their site](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14052) that leads be to believe that their current solution is to manually stop the server and quit before shutdown.

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support, as this is a commercial product? And are you actually using the current version of MAMP Pro? Their [downloads page](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html) states the compatibility in a way that suggests an earlier version might not have been compatible.

Comment: I am using the most current version 2.0.3 from 8/29/11 (I think I updated yesterday in hopes that would fix this problem)  I also submitted a ticket which I've never heard anything from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I "threw in the towel" so to speak.

I got rid of MAMP Pro in place of using MacPorts to install Apache/MySQL and PHP on my own.  (I used these instructions to do so: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP)

The downside is the loss of the interface to create virtual hosts but a combination of my local hosts file, apache's httpd-vhosts.conf and TextMate and I'm all set.

Comment: Consider getting [VirtualHostX](http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/).